# Does the use of eye glasses prevent eye disease?

Tags: eye, disease, glasses

I'm turning 40 and went for my first eye test recently. They said I have nearsightedness. I work on a computer all day.

They gave me three quotes for eye glasses :

Option 1: (Cheapest price)
 
1.1 Single vision (standard)
1.2 SV ARC Stock

Option 2: (Average price)
2.1 Single vision (standard)
2.2 KF SV CLIMATEYES 1.56 STOCK ARC

Option 3: (Expensive)
3.1 Single vision (standard)
3.2 Accomodative support lens
3.3 Incredible flexi uncoated 1.5
3.4 Blue tech

I'm not sure which option I should choose or I should wait another year ?

If the test results of my eye test changes every year will I have to get new eye glasses each time meaning paying again ?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalScience.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor, or in this case, your optician. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Can the main question still be asked on its own merit ?

Comment: Yes it can @Albertus.  If you remove all references to your personal situation and [provide some prior research information](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), the question can remain open.